# Promise Based XHR returns Undefined - JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am building a web-server in node.js and making a call to my API for data. I wanted to clean up the code a bit by creating a XHR function (names AJAX) and call it in each of the routes. I understand this question has been asked in several variation, but even following through on all of these tutorials, I haven't been able to get a response.

XHR Function:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

exports.request = obj => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(obj.method || "GET", obj.url);
        if (obj.headers) {
            Object.keys(obj.headers).forEach(key => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(key, obj.headers[key]);
            });
        }
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                console.log(xhr.response);
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                console.log(xhr.statusText)
                reject(xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
        xhr.send(obj.body);
    });
};
```

How I'm calling it:

```
const AJAX = require('../ajax');

// G1: GET All Clubs
exports.get_all_clubs = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Return all Clubs:')
    AJAX.request({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/clubs",
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(data => {
            // Log out Data
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

And the response I am getting back:

```
GET /clubs - - ms - -
Return all Clubs:
undefined
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at AJAX.request.then.data (C:\Users\tyler\Desktop\Code\clubadmin\api\controllers\clubs.js:14:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

The API is working, and if I test the same route in POSTMAN it gives a correct response.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the `fetch` api instead of XHR. XHR is essentially deprecated and fetch is supported in all major browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Also, please update your answer and do a `console.log` on the entire response object. I'm willing to bet that you will learn something interesting from that.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Wow. I was pulling the wrong item from the response object. Thank you for the instant fix there. As far as using Fetch instead, does it provide the same function for GET/POST/PUT etc as the XHR request?

Comment: Yes, read the docs. It's a much more modern UI and supports promises natively.